# Email sent using PHPmalier Class image break in gmail, hotmail, yahoo

Tags: email, url, phpmailer

Hope you all are fine.

I am facing a very irritating problem using PHPmailer class. When I sent email everything is fine but some images in the email body are break **%0D+** sign is embedded into URL on **Gmail** and space is added on **Yahoo** and **Hotmail** for the same images.

I don't know why when I print email on the browser it is perfectly fine but on the email, it is not.

**Browser View** When I print email before sending.
[image]

**Gmail View** after sending the email.

[image]

**Here is the code of email body**

```
$bodyEmail  =   '<body style="background: #eee;">
                    <table cellpadding="5"  bgcolor="#fff" style="margin:0 auto;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 100%;  max-width: 700px; background-color: #FFF; margin:0 auto; " cellpadding="5">
                                    <tr style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                                        <td align="center" style="margin-bottom:20px"><img src="http://fwt-logi.com/new_fwt/newsite/images/logo-fwt-logistic.png" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="">
                                        <td style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color: #fff;  text-align:center; background-color:#173385;  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">Logistic Services for Small and Large Companies</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:20px;">
                                        <td  style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom:10px;  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" colspan="2"><strong>Dear : FWT LOGISTICS(TRS)</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table border="1" style="width:100%; max-width:700px; background-color: #FFF; margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #ccc;" cellpadding="5"  cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="50%" style="color: #173385; font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border:1px solid #ccc;"><strong>Chassis No. </strong></td>
                                        <td style="font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  border:1px solid #ccc;">'.$imagesRow['chassis_no'].'</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="50%" style="color: #173385; font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border:1px solid #ccc;"><strong>Make</strong></td>
                                        <td style="font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  border:1px solid #ccc;">'.$arr_mk[$imagesRow['make_id']].'</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="50%" style="color: #173385; font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border:1px solid #ccc;"><strong>Model</strong></td>
                                        <td style="font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border:1px solid #ccc;" >'.$arr_nm[$imagesRow['name_id']].'</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="50%" style="color: #173385; font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border:1px solid #ccc;"><strong>Engine No. </strong></td>
                                        <td style="font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border:1px solid #ccc;"'.$imagesRow['engine_no'].'></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table style="width: 100%;  max-width: 700px;background-color: #FFF; margin:20px 0px; margin:0 auto;  padding:10px; margin:0 auto;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bordercolor="333" align="center"><a href="'.SS_URL.'services/zip.php?chassis_no='.$imagesRow['chassis_no'].'"><img src="'.SS_IMG.'download-img.png" alt="Click here and download images" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table style="margin-top:15px 0px; width: 100%; max-width: 700px;background-color: #FFF; margin:0 auto;" cellpadding="5">
                                    <tr>';
                                        $i  =   '';
                                        foreach($allImages as $imgName){
                                            $bodyEmail  .=  '<td style="margin-top:20px; width:20%; padding:5px;"><img width="100%" src="'.$imagesURL.$imgName.'"/></td>';
                                            $i++;
                                            if($i%5==0){
                                                $bodyEmail  .=  "</tr><tr>";
                                            }
                                        }
                            $bodyEmail  .=  '</tr>
                                </table>
                                <table  style="width: 100%; max-width: 700px;background-color: #FFF; border-top:3px solid #333; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">If you have any questions please use JFA Direct Line.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2"><strong>Kobe</strong></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color: #173385; "><strong>Quality Control</strong></td>
                                                <td><i class="fa fa-ph"></i>080-6974-0670</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color: #173385;" ><strong>Inspector</strong></td>
                                                <td><i class="fa fa-ph"></i>080-6974-0670</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">(Sales Manager: Osamu Nishihara 080-6172-0680)</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2"><strong>Tokyo Bay</strong></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color: #173385; "><strong>Quality Control</strong></td>
                                                <td><i class="fa fa-ph"></i>080-6974-0671</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color: #173385; " ><strong>Inspector</strong></td>
                                                <td><i class="fa fa-ph"></i>080-6974-0672</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></body>';
```

Problem in this loop can you please tell me where i am wrong?

```
<table style="margin-top:15px 0px; width: 100%; max-width: 700px;background-color: #FFF; margin:0 auto;" cellpadding="5">
                                    <tr>';
                                        $i  =   '';
                                        foreach($allImages as $imgName){
                                            $bodyEmail  .=  '<td style="margin-top:20px; width:20%; padding:5px;"><img width="100%" src="'.$imagesURL.$imgName.'"/></td>';
                                            $i++;
                                            if($i%5==0){
                                                $bodyEmail  .=  "</tr><tr>";
                                            }
                                        }
                            $bodyEmail  .=  '</tr>
                                </table>
```

**Gmail OUT PUT code**

```
<tr>
            <td><img width="100px" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/pKuau8twpVJ61cLvY1g-nQahBHu7lqUm3NwyA-Z-0fxf_ASZlK6SvHTFiRbot11r1AGDahiuhKcNyidOjGAH0bYdIGUV2Uvdq6nJJyBGM_4KM4H5ZXxWytT4_yfFq7c0vCM=s0-d-e1-ft#http://fwt-logi.com/uploaded_files/image/thumb/1175065_21_115_1528884248.jpg" class="CToWUd"></td>
            <td><img width="100px" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/e9Geo989EDQoLjtN72wDFDHRVnq6q8agHfx_Fzi188L0dv2YXeAJjDg8_IvmbdzMwemWT4-1ee-cHSCjqPJ2iSrTUrr3bhAIcpYgoCSxso8t-kX0ubA5bUfYLg5ap1iDwyg=s0-d-e1-ft#http://fwt-logi.com/uploaded_files/image/thumb/1175065_20_786_1528884248.jpg" class="CToWUd"></td>
            <td><img width="100px" src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/ZVXoQ0-s5xQXJ6J7WHXHhH9U0iBCfcUVe2YnyW46ouRj-gXpeWPSQ0HScQ5PL0P-aHg_xNbf1dL3f3lE18fqAB-Trfd20xpmztWwuEN3OLitxc0u4d1p4aAIqN3TInUP-hoH8X9B=s0-d-e1-ft#http://fwt-logi.com/uploaded_files/im%0D+age/thumb/1175065_15_715_1528884247.jpg" class="CToWUd"></td>
            <td><img width="100px" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/PZFG0lssYX5QeqQQPVqqCjjsguHN4gu6Cspp_qy-kQ7PrkTHjYpeJzDiggAnalLCsQkAkKF8IR6O7cZUXc53yeGtGjVAwnZIXPnM3GMEo6zKcKdvW1xXmsamm0kotWy1Frs=s0-d-e1-ft#http://fwt-logi.com/uploaded_files/image/thumb/1175065_16_600_1528884247.jpg" class="CToWUd"></td>
            <td><img width="100px" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/aPH9AMu4mds0NE0cFRjF_jGboAAjwzqKArbrXmHYJv8G9LdMnaR2Gml-92Q3ldfXOhoaYECuuMJWZaZlqMz7d5gKQsbITNjKo5As37-pMC0JLn0nwsIcDznPJLRF9CWy0Ps=s0-d-e1-ft#http://fwt-logi.com/uploaded_files/image/thumb/1175065_18_449_1528884248.jpg" class="CToWUd"></td>
            <td><img width="100px" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/7dWlo34WF6FoNIZSNN3noBko4yfEDiBvalgBFelcYQaQ84WQrfxaP_3eSUvXz2ssAe7P7uDi7L0Y2qUFQFKO-FZ58Ltuf1p5azscisXVe2ZNogjHh_avbNLhUtloeG2jWQ=s0-d-e1-ft#http://fwt-logi.com/uploaded_files/image/thumb/1175065_8_820_1528884247.jpg" class="CToWUd"></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Are you using latest PHPMailer 6.0+?

Comment: No i am using Version: 5.2.4.

Comment: So update. Don’t be surprised that an old, buggy, and vulnerable version is old and has bugs.

Comment: I try with the new version but same error exists.

Comment: Can you post part of a received message body showing the extra characters in context?

Comment: On gmail **%0D+** character show in image url.

Comment: That's not what I asked, and it's not enough to go on. Show me a few lines from a received message that contains these chars, add it to your question.

Comment: mydomainname/uploaded%0D+_files/image/thumb/1175065_15_715_1528884247.jpg

Comment: mydomainname/uploaded
_files/image/thumb/1175065_15_715_1528884247.jpg

Comment: PHPMailer can add line breaks as part of quoted-printable encoding, but they would appear as `=0D`, not the url-encoded form. Also I can't tell without seeing the context that thee appear in; it would also be useful to see more than one, *in context*. Drip-feeding me vital info is not a useful way of getting your question answered.

Comment: Add update the question can you please take a look.

Comment: You already posted that code; we need to see the rendered output, as received in a message; in gmail, view the message source and post the relevant bit in your question.

Comment: Gmail output code past please see.

Comment: Does this occur only in gmail or in other places too?

Comment: In others like HOTMAIL AND YAHOO line break is added.

Comment: Are you sending using SMTP? Sending via `mail()` (PHPMailer's default) can sometimes have line break issues.

Comment: I traied both way but the error reamin same.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference and others might get help with this. Just update your PHPMALIER class, and always use UTF-8 encoding in the header.

1. Use update class.
2. Use UTF-8 in your header.
3. Using table structure in email, div, and others might not work as expected.
4. Always use inline CSS to fix changes.